# Action wp_login_failed not working if only one field is filled out

Tags: login, actions, wp-redirect, wp-login-form

I created a login form in the frontend with `wp_login_form()`.
In my **functions.php** file I added an action to prevent the redirect to **/wp-login.php** if the login failed with

> add_action('wp_login_failed', ….

As it turns out the action only hooks if the **username** and **password** fields are filled in. If one of them is left empty I still get redirected to **wp-login.php.**

Is there a possibility to check if both fields are filled in to prevent the redirect?

Thanks

Julian

Answer (score 4):

Add this filter to change how blank username/password is treated:

```
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'custom_authenticate_username_password', 30, 3);
function custom_authenticate_username_password( $user, $username, $password )
{
    if ( is_a($user, 'WP_User') ) { return $user; }

    if ( empty($username) || empty($password) )
    {
        $error = new WP_Error();
        $user  = new WP_Error('authentication_failed', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: Invalid username or incorrect password.'));

        return $error;
    }
}
```

And then your original redirect on wp_login_failed will work with blank username/password as well.

Comment: really nice job...THx...

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with the function `wp_authenticate()` (found in the file `pluggable.php`)

You have 2 options.

- hack the wordpress core (not advised!)
- write your own plugin that overrides `wp_authenticate()` (this is merely deleting a few characters in an *if* statement).